# Running Gitlab CI behind custom authentication?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I just tried installing gitlab-ce on my Debian host with Gitlab's APT repositories. I pulled [this example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/php) and pushed it to my host with a runner configured and got the following error:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.7.2 (998cf5d)
Using Docker executor with image php:5.6 ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner:service ...
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner:cache ...
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner:build ...
Pulling docker image php:5.6 ...

Running on runner-4d0395b6-project-2-concurrent-0 via gitlab...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/d33tah/gitlab-ci-test'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxx@gitlab.somedomain.com/d33tah/gitlab-ci-test.git/'

ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

Pointing the runner to http://localhost/ci didn't help either. Will I have to remove my HTTPS authentication for the tool to work?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want to do? Are you using basic HTTP authentication for a private repository or are you using .htaccess protection for your gitlab instance? As far as I know, it is recommended to use deploy keys for accessing repositories as a machine or build tool. In addition to this, please add your GL, GLCI and GLCIR versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hosting the website over SSL and making sure that gitlab.somedomain.com points to localhost so that https://gitlab.somedomain.com needed no authentication locally. Since I also wanted a Docker runner, I had to set up a local DNS server and make Docker use it.